# Out of Memory Exception Windows 7 32 bit - Windows Application

Tags: .net, memory, windows-7, 32-bit

I am getting "out of memory" exception in Windows Application in Win 7 32 bit OS. But the same application is working fine in Win XP. Tried running .NET Mem Profiler but it is not showing any leaks. Is there any settings we can do in OS to get rid of this error without any code change?

Comment: what is using most memory in the profiler stats?

Comment: byte[] is consuming more memory

Comment: use ETW to analyze memory usage grow: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial/Tutorial-10-Investigating-NET-Heap-Memory-Leaks-Part1-Collecting-the-data , https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial/Tutorial-11-Investigating-NET-Heap-Memory-Leaks-Part2-Analyzing-the-data